# .htaccess RewriteRule Redirect works on htaccess tester, does not work on server

Tags: .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file defined at www.mydomain/documentation/.htaccess and am trying to redirect a number of broken links to a specific page.

The .htaccess file contains the Rewrite Rule

```
RewriteRule ^/?(documentation/PresentationCore~System\.Windows\.RoutedEventArgs).*$ 
             /documentation/v4.x/SciChart_WPF_v4_SDK_User_Manual.html [R,L,NC]
```

> **Note**: RewriteEngine ON has already been defined. Other rules are being applied

Now in [.htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) the rule is being evaluated and redirects correctly when the following URL is requested:

`www.mydomain.com/documentation/PresentationCore~System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs~Handled.html`

However, when the same domain is entered into the browser, I get a 404 not found for this page.

I can confirm I have uploaded .htaccess to the correct folder and cleared the server cache.

Is there anything else I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: It might be worth looking in the server error log which path the 404 is being thrown for, exactly.

Comment: The redirect target does exist, the request does not. I just got this helpful info from the tech support of the webhost "redirects in the .htaccess is a hit or miss on our platform. You should perform 301 redirects in your my.wpengine.com. That will work out much more." :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to match the folder name if htaccess is already in that folder, try :

```
RewriteRule ^/?(PresentationCore~System\.Windows\.RoutedEventArgs).*$ 
             /documentation/v4.x/SciChart_WPF_v4_SDK_User_Manual.html [R,L,NC]
```

Comment: This actually works, the problem appears to be the host, wpengine.com, who says they have a hit & miss htaccess engine ...